# Firebase Assistant missing in Android studio's Tools tab

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-assistant

So I'm building an application with android studio and I am having problems connecting to  Firebase.  This means that Firebase assistant is not in Tools. Now, all my firebase plugins are enabled, I have logged into android studio with my Google account. And I saw a suggestion that enabling Google Repository in SDK-> Tools will work.

Now, 'Google repository' is missing in the Tools section. I tried updating SDK Tools/Platform tools (as advised by someone on this forum) I still couldn't find the Google Repo.

System info: Linux